# sending and recieving a file in Nodejs with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a server and a client with Node.js, the server uses express and the client uses axios.

I'm trying to send an image file from the client to the server. I found somewhere here this bit of code for the client:

```
let file = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("picture", file);

let post_config = {
    method: "post",
    url: SERVER_PICTURE_URL,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
    data: form_data
}
axios(post_config).then(_ => {console.log("sent");} );
```

But I can't figure out what's supposed to be on the server side. I've tried the most obvious solution, writing `response.data` or `response.form` to a file, but both are undefined.

Is there some parser I'm supposed to use? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the client that you wrote, but in express, you need to use `express-fileupload` package for getting the picture from req.files

```
    const express = require('express');
    const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
    const app = express();
    const port = 3000;
    app.use(fileupload());
    
    app.post('/picture', (req, res) => {
      const files=req.files;
      res.send(files)
    })

    app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

Comment: thanks, this works! I figured out what was wrong with the client, too